# Passenger No Such File To Load config/environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, passenger

I was trying to make some simple changes to an old app of mine (Rails 3.0.0, Ruby 1.8.7) last night and ran into a number of issues upon deploy. I'm using Moonshine to handle deploys.

I can run `cap deploy` without error, but then I get the following Passenger error

```
no such file to load -- /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409025824/config/environment
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but when I ssh into the box, the whole config folder under `/srv/BBRatboard/current/config` is empty. Is this by design or is something going wrong in my deploy?

A number of people have been able to solve this by adjusting the permissions on the `environment.rb` file (https://www.sit.auckland.ac.nz/Ruby_on_Rails_deployment), but I'm not even able to see it on my production server.

I can provide any details necessary, any help would be GREATLY appreciated as the app is currently in a broken state.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you have any logs or record of how the files were uploaded to your server during the deployment?

Comment: Do you know where those might be stored?

Comment: This is the output when I run cap deploy: https://gist.github.com/naderhen/5342726

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need files to be present within your `config` directory. It looks like your `cap deploy` output shows it it is deleting the release's `config` directory:

> executing "chmod -R -- g+w /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459 && rm -rf -- /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/system && ln -s -- /srv/BBRatboard/shared/system /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/system && rm -rf -- /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/log && ln -s -- /srv/BBRatboard/shared/log /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/log && rm -rf -- /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/pids && ln -s -- /srv/BBRatboard/shared/pids /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/pids && rm -rf -- /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/config && ln -s -- /srv/BBRatboard/shared/config /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/config"

(look at the end, `rm -ff -- /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/config`). Although its also trying to symlink the `config` directory to the `shared/config` directory (`ln -s -- /srv/BBRatboard/shared/config /srv/BBRatboard/releases/20130409032459/config`)

I'm guessing that the `shared/config` directory is created during `cap deploy:setup` (based on the [Moonshine docs](https://github.com/railsmachine/moonshine/wiki/Tutorial) which recommend running it before `cap deploy`). I would ensure you have run the `cap deploy:setup` task beforehand, and check that your `shared/config` directory has contents such as the `environment.rb` file it claims is missing.

Comment: I ran the cap deploy:setup command first and that does create the shared/config folder..unfortunately that folder is empty as well. I'm not entirely sure why it would be doing that?

Comment: You may need to run through some of the steps on this page too https://github.com/railsmachine/moonshine/wiki/Shared-Configuration-Files

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging, it looks like this is an issue of differing versions of capistrano/moonshine and the way they handle the shared assets.

I followed a suggestion at https://github.com/railsmachine/moonshine/wiki/Moonshine.yml-files-not-being-loaded-or-configuration-object-appears-empty

namely replacing config with tmp and it seems to work for now!